# Angular Value Changes - Set Property then update ngFor - Not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've got what feels like a very simple component. I call an API which returns an array of objects, many of them. Once loaded into a property, I have a select list the the user can choose a suite from, then using value changes, I filter the property and save the results to a new property, then using ngfor, iterate over those values. But, even though value changes is working and the name gets updated, the main table isn't populating with values. Cant figure out why

////// TS /////

```
export class SchedulesComponent implements OnInit {
  // PAGINATION
  scheduleItemsFound;
  currentPage = 1;
  itemsPerPage = 10;
  pageSize: number;

  scheduleSelectForm: FormGroup;
  suiteSchedule;
  chosenSuiteName;
  schedules;
  suites = [
    'Stage 1',
    'Suite 1',
    'Suite 2',
    'Suite 3',
    'Suite 4',
    'Suite 5',
    'Suite 6',
    'Suite 7',
    'Suite 8',
    'Suite 9',
    'Suite 10',
    'Suite 11',
    'Audio Edit Asst 1',
    'Audio Edit Asst 2',
    'Audio Edit Asst 3',
    'Audio Edit Asst 4',
    'Audio Edit 1',
    'Audio Edit 2',
    'Audio Edit 3',
    'Audio Offsite Edit',
    'Audio Offsite Mix',
    'AE Avid 1',
    'AE Avid 2',
    'AE Avid 3',
    'Transfer 1',
    'Transfer 2',
    'Transfer 3',
    'QC Bay 1'
  ];
  constructor(
    private _scheduleService: ScheduleService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    // Initialize form
    this.scheduleSelectForm = this._fb.group({
      scheduleSelect: ['']
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get schedules
    this._scheduleService.getSchedules().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.schedules = response['schedules'];
      },
      error => console.log(error['message'])
    );

    // Form value changes
    this.scheduleSelectForm
      .get('scheduleSelect')
      .valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.chosenSuiteName = value;

        this.suiteSchedule = this.schedules.filter(sched => {
          sched.LOCATION == value;
        });
      });
  }

////// HTML

<div class="card" *ngIf="schedules; else loading">
  <div class="card-header bg-light text-primary">
    <h3>All Schedules</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body border border-light">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <form [formGroup]="scheduleSelectForm">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label>Select Schedule</label>
              <select class="custom-select form-control" formControlName="scheduleSelect">
                <option *ngFor="let s of suites" value="{{s}}">
                  {{ s }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="card mt-3" *ngIf="suiteSchedule">
  <div class="card-header bg-light text-primary">
    <h4>{{ chosenSuiteName }}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body border border-light">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thead>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Day</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Duration</th>
          <th>Project</th>
          <th>Episode</th>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>Operator</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let sched of suiteSchedule">
            <td>{{ sched.T_START * 1000 | date: 'MMM d'}}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.T_START * 1000 | date:'EEE' }}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.T_START * 1000 | date:'shortTime' }} - {{ sched.T_END * 1000 | date:'shortTime' }}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.WODURATION }}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.PROJECT }}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.PROD_EP }}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.SERVICES }}</td>
            <td>{{ sched.PERSONNEL }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Loading text -->
<ng-template #loading>
  Loading Schedules...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: can you  add some sample data for `this.schedules`  so that we can work on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change in arrow function because it will return something if you are using curly braces, reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
this.suiteSchedule = this.schedules.filter(sched => {
    return (sched.LOCATION == this.chosenSuiteName);
});
```